# 403 errors with Amazon S3 when loading static files

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-django-storages

I am building a Django app and try to use an Amazon S3 bucket to store static files like JavaScript and CSS.
I successfully uploaded the static files, and I can see that through the Amazon S3 console. But I get 403 errors when my site tries to load static files from my bucket.
So I checked my permissions and made sure the Amazon S3 bucket is accessible to anyone.

But I still get 403 errors in inspector.

i don't think my settings.py is related to this, but I show you my settings.py in case it's relevant to the problem.

```
# AWS S3 Static Files Configuration
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = config('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    'atgs_project/static',
]
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'us-west-2'
AWS_S3_USE_SSL = False
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = "https://my-ecommerce-app-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/"
```

THank you in advance.

Comment: I really hope that the bucket name in `AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL` is not a real bucket name, especially if you have opened the bucket to the world. Also, when you say "when my site tries to load static files from my S3 bucket" do you mean that it should *always* load data from the S3 bucket or just *once*?

Comment: No. The bucket name in`AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL` is not real. And it should always load data from the S3 bucket, not just once.